# Keep selection visible in RichTextBox like in Notepad

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

When I bring up the "Search for..." window in Notepad, and the text is found, this text is highlighted in Notepad. I guess this works internally by selecting.

The Search For window is still active.

I tried to re-write Notepad, but for a textbox, I chose a RichTextBox.
As soon as the RichTextBox loses focus, the selection is also lost.

The selection is only shown again when I set the focus to the RichTextBox again.

How would I prevent the RichTextBox from loses the visible selection?

Comment: So you do not want to **hide** the **selection** when the RTB loses focus.  Now if there was just a property on the RTB that controlled that behavior, then life would be grand.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "HideSelection" property of your RichTextBox to false. Hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this image is big enough.